# problem when accessing sharepoint site externally

Tags: sharepoint-2007

i have created a sharepoint site urls:
 internal url : http://orbsp:2323
 external url : http://orbsp.com:2323.
when i am trying to access from other computers,its not opening.
plesae help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) try pinging it
2) if ping works, look further into IIS settings.
3) if ping doesn't work, try nslookup from the command line
4) if it doesn't resolve, check your DNS settings.
5) if it resolves, but you cannot ping it, check your firewall settings on the server network.

Answer (score 1):

Are your [Alternate Access Mappings](http://www.google.com/search?q=sharepoint+alternate+access+mappings) correctly configured?